# Get Shipping Methods by postCode and countryId

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, adminhtml, backend, shipping-methods

I want to get all the available shipping methods along with their prices by postCode and countryId in a page which is not Checkout page.

Example: I have CountryId as 'IN' and postCode as '560029' in a phtml file of backend orders page. Now i want to get all the available shipping methods with their prices which will be displayed for the customer in frontend in checkout page as follows.

[image]

Please let me know how can i get all the shipping methods with their prices using countryId and postCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Magento Stack Exchange Viewers,

I found the answer in one of the Question - [Magento : Get all Shipping Rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934138/magento-get-all-shipping-rates)

and the answer is:

```
// Change to your postcode / country.
$zipcode = '560029';
$country = 'IN';

// Update the cart's quote.
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$address = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
$address->setCountryId($country)
        ->setPostcode($zipcode)
        ->setCollectShippingrates(true);
$cart->save();

// Find if our shipping has been included.
$rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
                 ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
    foreach ($carrier as $rate) {
        print_r($rate->getData());
    }
}
```